# Convert TreeMap to two arrays, cast problem

Tags: java, android, arrays, casting

I need to convert TreeMap into two arrays. I have problem with casting. It says `Inconvertible types. Cannot cast java.lan.Double to float`. Code:

```
ArrayList<Float> yData = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> xData = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                xData.add(entry.getKey()) ;
                yData.add(entry.getValue());  <---------- error
        }
```

I tried to get double values first and than cast to float but I have the same problem:

```
ArrayList<Double> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Float> yData = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> xData = new ArrayList<>();


            for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                xData.add(entry.getKey()) ;
                temp.add(entry.getValue());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
            yData.add((float) temp.get(i));    <---------- error
        }
```

I also used the normal arrays but the effect was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a `Double` you should use `floatValue()`:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
    yData.add(temp.get(i).floatValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`
  You can use the floatvalue method

```
 for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
            yData.add((temp.get(i).floatValue());   
        }
```